# How to find object with same parameter in two arrays and replace a parameter from one to eachother

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays with different data in it.
But they have some objects in common i want to search two arrays by their id and give one's title to eachother that does not have title.

```
    ARecords: [
  { 
    id:  34,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  35,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  36,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  37,
    title: null
  },
```

},]

```
BRecords: [
  { 
    id:  34,
    title: 'realtitle2'
  },
  { 
    id:  39,
    title: 'realtitle1'
  },
  { 
    id:  37,
    title: 'realtitle'
  },
```

},]

I would really appreicate if someone can help

Comment: Can you write `function titleForId(id) {}` ? It's job would be to `find` an object in `BRecords` with a matching id and return its title.

Comment: What you have tried so far?, can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) methods to first create a hash lookup of elements with titles, then merge all elements that have the same `id` into a new array like so:

```js
const ARecords = [
  { 
    id:  34,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  35,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  36,
    title: null
  },
  { 
    id:  37,
    title: null
  },
]

const BRecords = [
  { 
    id:  34,
    title: 'realtitle2'
  },
  { 
    id:  39,
    title: 'realtitle1'
  },
  { 
    id:  37,
    title: 'realtitle'
  },
]

// create a hash of titled records for quick lookup
const BRecordHash = BRecords.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.id] = cur
  return acc
}, {})

// merge titles with their corresponding id (if present)
const mergedTitles = ARecords.map(item => {
  const correspondingElement = BRecordHash[item.id]
  if (!correspondingElement) return item
  item.title = BRecordHash[item.id].title
  return item
})

// output result
console.log(mergedTitles)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const titleForID = (
  arrayWithTitles,
  arrayWithoutTitles
) => {
  // a shallow copy of arrayWithoutTitles
  const slice = {... arrayWithoutTitles}

  for (const i of arrayWithoutTitles) {
    for (const j of arrayWithTitles) {
      if (arrayWithoutTitles[i].id === arrayWithTitles[j].id) {
        slice[i].title = arrayWithTitles[j].title
      }
    }
  }

  return slice
}
```

Comment: This isn't an optimized approach (the time complexity could be reduced with a hash map), but it's a viable solution.